# C# - Convert a List System.Object[] to List System.Int32[]

Tags: c#, list, odoo, int32

**i'm new to C#**,

I'm trying to use a function that as been created [here](https://github.com/ieski/OdooXmlRpc/blob/master/Odoo/Concrete/RpcRecord.cs#:%7E:text=public%20void%20SetFieldValue,%7D)

Actually i don't know how to return a list as array as a parameter.
This function right here will use the "`write`" method of Odoo API.

```
    public void SetFieldValue(string field, object value)
    {
        var fieldAttribute = _fieldsResult.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FieldName == field);
        if (fieldAttribute == null) return;

        fieldAttribute.Changed = fieldAttribute.Changed == false;

        fieldAttribute.Value = value;
    }
```

So i did like this but it don't works :

```
  foreach (var result in results)
  {
       result.SetFieldValue("payment_method_ids", _NewPaymentLine.ToArray());
       result.Save();
  }
```

_NewPaymentLine is a List that i filled list this :

```
var _NewPaymentLine = new List<object>();
_NewPaymentLine.Add(new object[] { 4, Payment_Ids.GetField("id").Value });
```

All i can say its that the `input value` is a `System.Object[]` type and the `output value` is a `System.Int32[]` type.

Actually, what i return with the SetFieldValue is a System.Object[], but i think i have to return an System.Int32[], so the question is, how can i do to make my List of System.Object[] into System.Int32[]

Thanks in advance, i hope that someone can help me.

Comment: What is the question? I don't really get it. How to return an array from a method in C#?

Comment: Actually, what i return with the SetFieldValue is a System.Object[], but i think i have to return an System.Int32[], so the question is, how can i do to make my List of System.Object[] into  System.Int32[]

Comment: You will have to create a new array. You cannot "cast" the existing array. Do something like `int[] resultArray = Array.ConvertAll(inputArray, x => (int)x);` where `inputArray` is your object array - or if you need to convert a `string` (or whatever else your object might be), use something like `Convert.ToInt32(x)` instead of `(int)x`.

Comment: So, i tried to do it but i cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>[]' because my inputArray is a list

Comment: Your error says that you have a `List<object>` however an array of  `List<object>` (`List<ojbect>[]`) is expected. This sounds weird... maybe a mistake on your side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you pretend, but you have to create a function to convert from your Object to Int

```
public List<int> DoConvert(List<Object> objectsList){
    List<int> intList = new List<int>();
    foreach(var object in objectsList)
    {
        intList.Add(object.MyNumber)       //Input your logic here
    }
    return intList;
}
```

Comment: `object` will for sure not have `.MyNumber`. This might be a bit missleading to a beginner. I suggest to have some kind of "sample convert" of `object`. Also you're missing a function name.

Comment: @Dominik, `RpcField` doesn't appear defined on the link he provided, I assumed it would have other properties, and he only wanted to save some of them, hence my "Input your logic here". Also while creating a more abstract function with List<T> return could not achieve what he pretended, since I assumed he would need to access specific properties.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, it was a problem similary to it